# Is there a way to configure Rails 3 to log SQL queries in its own log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my dev environment, all logs are saved to `logs/development.log`.  The log file contains SQL queries performed in each web page as well as other noise.  Is there a way to configure Rails 3 to only log those queries in a separate log file?  I'm currently using 3.2.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `config/environments/development.rb` file you can do something like this:

```
config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")
```